# Rating not add with ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, rating-system

I have a problem
There is a rating system on songs (Its not my code i debugging it). but it could not add or update or show me the rating.

here is my code:
Ajax.js

```
function bindEvents() {
                $(cssSelector.rating_succes).css('display','none');
                //Set the new rating when the user clicks
                $(cssSelector.ratingLevel).click(function() {
                    var $this = $(this), rating = $this.parent().children().index($this) + 1, index;

                    var trackname   =   $(cssSelector.title+':first').text();

                    var postdata1   =   'action=my_special_ajax_call5&rating='+rating+'&trackname='+trackname;  
                    alert(postdata1);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:ajaxurl,
                        cache:false,
                        data: postdata1,
                        beforeSend:function(){

                        },
                        success:function(res){
                            $(cssSelector.rating_succes).html(res).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
                            //window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000);
                        }
                });
                    $this.prevAll().add($this).addClass(attr(cssSelector.ratingLevelOn)).end().end().nextAll().removeClass(attr(cssSelector.ratingLevelOn));
                });
            }
```

Proccess.php

```
function implement_ajax5(){

global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix."songs";
$table1 = $wpdb->prefix."rating";

$song_title = strip_tags($_POST['trackname']);
$rating_value = strip_tags($_POST['rating']);

$songres = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `title`='$song_title'") or die(mysql_error());
$song_id = $songres->id;
$total_votes = $songres->total_votes;
$total_votes = $total_votes+1;

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$data = array(
    'song_id' => $song_id,
    'rating_value' => $rating_value,
    'user_ip' => $ip
);


$check = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE song_id='$song_id' AND user_ip='$ip'");
if(!$check){

$insert = $wpdb->insert($table1,$data);


$wpdb->update( 
    $table, 
    array(
        'total_votes' => $total_votes,
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => $song_id ) 

) or die(mysql_error());
echo 'Thank you';
}else{echo 'Already rated';}    

die();

}
```

index.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_ajax_call5', 'implement_ajax5');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_ajax_call5', 'implement_ajax5');//for users that are not logged in.
```

I dont understand what happen when i alert it shows me right values but not add or update in database.

Comment: use `$wpdb->show_errors();`.. it will show you query errors if any occured...

Comment: after this no error show

Comment: Where is the action in your ajax call? I don't see it? edit: apologies, I just found it

Comment: try `$rowCount = $wpdb->num_rows;` and use `if($rowCount!=0)` instead of `if(!$check)`....

Comment: Nothing happen - i think my ajax does not go to process file, but i dont get the point to where i check that my ajax go to process page or not

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have firebug addon on firefox? If yes, then use console window of it to debug

Comment: ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok just try this in your Ajax.js at top of the page

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
```

And every thing goes perfect

and i think in your process page there is no need to update query. If you want to delete this there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

i get this a lot........ajaxurl needs to be defined, so i've learned that its just easier to not use ajaxurl and put in "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" in the url section.

Also i dont see you using non-conflict jQuery? (use the word jQuery instead of $)

You may also have issues with your postdata string, i may be wrong but what you need is action: '' ,
rating: '',

etc.

A good practice is to var_dump $_POST and exit at the beginning of your function to make sure they are passing over correctly. then in success- console.log(res) or whatever you are calling your return data

```
function bindEvents() {
            jQuery(cssSelector.rating_succes).css('display','none');
            //Set the new rating when the user clicks
            jQuery(cssSelector.ratingLevel).click(function() {
                var $this =  jQuery(this), rating = $this.parent().children().index($this) + 1, index;

                var trackname   =    jQuery(cssSelector.title+':first').text();

                //alert(postdata1); -> console.log() is better for looking at objects 
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    cache:false,
                    data: {
                        action: 'my_special_ajax_call5',
                        rating: rating,
                        trackname: trackname
                    }

                    success:function(output){
                        console.log(output)
                        jQuery(cssSelector.rating_succes).html(output).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
                        //window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000);
                    }
            });
                $this.prevAll().add($this).addClass(attr(cssSelector.ratingLevelOn)).end().end().nextAll().removeClass(attr(cssSelector.ratingLevelOn));
            });
        }
```

see how you get on with that :)

Comment: Nothing happen i'll try every thing you said

Comment: would love to know who marked this down......if anyone was to look above ajaxurl issue was solved + a couple of other potential probs he may have been having......

Comment: David your 'url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",' this line does not work and with deemi answer it work perfectly, So dont worry i vote u plus

Comment: thanks for putting it back, the url should work, its the same result as Deemi's answer! but sure glad you have it working :)